# Passing an ArrayList of a class from a jsp to a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of a class Room. I need to send it from a jsp to a servlet.

It seems the only way an html or a jsp can send values to a servlet is via a form, the method I tried was to pass it as a hidden parameter as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="allRooms" value="<%=request.getAttribute("allRooms") %>" />
```

But in the servlet to which i submit this form I get a compile error "String cannot be converted to List" for the following:

```
 List<Room> allRooms=(List<Room>)request.getParameter("allRooms");
```

Just converting the parameter to an Object type first and then converting it to a List as shown below gives the same exception but this time as a Runtime Exception:

```
 Object a=(Object)request.getParameter("allRooms");
 List<Room> allRooms=(List<Room>)a;
```

Is there any method to pass the List to the servlet or I will have to set it as a session variable in the JSP ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please understand that a jsp outputs HTML. When a browser submits a form, it sends an http request with the text values in the HTML. There are no Java objects involved at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any method to pass the List to the servlet or I will have to set it as a session variable in the JSP ?

Use `session`.That is one best solution.

There is no way to represent an `ArrayList` in HTML to send via html form. Use `session` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you pass the following params, and array is formed in servlet side

```
param[0]=ss , param[1]=ssw
```

You could do this.

```
List<String> roomParams =(List<String>)request.getParameter("param");
```

But to make this.

```
List<Room> allRooms=(List<Room>)request.getParameter("allRooms");
```

That I think is not possible, so you should use Session attributes

```
session.setAttribute("allRooms", new ArrayList<Room>());
```

Comment: Request attributes are not appropriate.

Comment: You are right, update my response to use session instead of request that will disappear once user change the page.

Comment: If I use the request attribute, I will have to send it through a request.getRequestDispatcher and my form inputs will not be sent. Also I am sending the details via a form. So its either the form details or the List. Can't send both !
I guess using session is the only solution ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should not be sending the `List` to `Servlet` directly and should look out for other options.

How are you generating the `ArrayList` on the browser page? If it is generated from a multi-select element from UI, then you can access the request parameter values as `Array` in `Servlet`.

Shishir